# Where in Moscow is/was this 1980 Olympics logo sculpture located?

Tags: where-on-earth, locate-this, moscow, artworks, olympics

The photo below ([source](https://twitter.com/sovietvisuals/status/1369619042546315264/photo/1)) was purportedly taken in 1980 in Moscow.

[image: A black and white photo showing a large billboard of Leonid Brezhnev, with what looks to be a large steel sculpture of the 1980 Summer Olympics emblem in the background.]

Exactly where in Moscow was the photo taken?  Is the sculpture of the 1980 Summer Olympics emblem in the background still standing at that location?  If not, has it been moved to anywhere else where I can see it?

Comment: It appears to be an [AP Press photo](http://www.apimages.com/metadata/Index/Associated-Press-International-News-Russian-Fed-/80be8e8058e4da11af9f0014c2589dfb/7/0), and as such has shown up in several news articles online.  But the information there doesn't really help narrow down the location.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [the internets](https://pastvu.com/p/9848), this is [the split of Leningradsky and Volokolamsky Chaussée](https://yandex.com/maps/-/CCUQ6TRE1B):

[image: The one which is not completely obscured by a banner]

These steles were not built to last and are torn down in most places, but there surely must be some remaining, such as [this one in Podol'sk](https://yandex.com/maps/-/CCUQb6aO3D) (ironically, behind a McDonalds):

[image: Podolsk Olympics 1980 stele]

Comment: The building is a plausible match for the one in the photo (albeit with a new front entrance and parking lot), though this leaves open the question of the present location of the sculpture.

Comment: This is a logo of the olympics, made from stock metal tubes. There were probably thousands of such sculptures all around the USSR. The town of 25,000 where I was born had one just like this one. Both are thoroughly rotten and torn down by today, I bet.

Comment: https://pastvu.com/p/884380 has a zoomed out version of the original photo

Comment: @alamar I see!  If these sculptures were indeed mass-produced, then I'd settle for learning where I might see any extant copy, not necessarily the one pictured in the photo I posted.

Comment: I have updated my answer.

Comment: There is also a [1981 Russia, Moscow, Northern AO, Sokol District](https://pastvu.com/p/884402) version of the same area as the [1980 Russia, Moscow, Northern AO, Sokol District](https://pastvu.com/p/884380) version from @thelem comment. The Summer Olympics emblem cannot be seen.

Comment: @MarkJohnson This photo is greatly zoomed out (the whole building is visible), making me thinking it was shot from the different side of the road, and the Olympics stele was still somewhere out there. The portrait of Brezhnev is also a different one.